# Complex exponential squared does not equal sinusoid squared?

Tags: complex-numbers

I just noticed this today and I'm a bit confused by it.

If we represent cos(x) as the real part of exp(i*x), then I always thought that we could then say that cos(x)^2 is equal to the real part of exp(i*x)*exp(i*x)=exp(2*i*x).  However, this clearly cannot be correct, as the real part of exp(2*i*x) is actually cos(2*x), which of course is not equal to cos(x)^2.

So what rule am I violating here when I try to represent cos(x)^2 as exp(2*i*x)?  Why can't I just say cos(x)^2 is equal to the real part of exp(i*x)*exp(i*x)=exp(2*i*x)?

I know I'm going wrong somewhere but can't see where.  Thanks!

Comment: One hint $\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}$

Answer (score 3):

You are not violating a rule, rather, you are making up a rule which does not exist.  You are assuming that the real part of $z^2$ is (the real part of $z$), squared.  But in fact if we write $z=a+ib$ then
$$z^2=a^2-b^2+2iab\ ,\quad \Re(z^2)=a^2-b^2$$
while
$$\Re z=a\ ,\quad (\Re z)^2=a^2\ ,$$
and these are not equal (except in the special case $b=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Be slow when you're writing these things out; $e^{2ix}=\left(e^{ ix}\right)^2=\left(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\right)^2=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)+2i\cos(x)\sin(x)$. Hence, $\Re(e^{2ix})=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\neq \cos^2(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't assume that the following holds:

$$\Re^2(z)=\Re(z^2).$$

($\Re$ denotes the real part of.)

Indeed,

$$\Re^2(x+iy)=x^2$$ while

$$\Re((x+iy)^2)=x^2-y^2.$$

---

Anyway, you can exploit the squaring as follows:

$$(e^{i\theta})^2=e^{i2\theta}$$ so that, taking the real parts,

$$\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\cos2\theta.$$

Then using $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ (from $|e^{i\theta}|^2=1$),

$$2\cos^2\theta=\cos2\theta+1.$$